# How to get synsets using sentiwordnet and calculate their sentiment score

Tags: python-3.x

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import sentiwordnet as swn,SentiSynset
swn.senti_synsets('slow')
```

for this code in python 3.4.3 i am getting output as:

```
<filter object at 0x0806DE70>
```

But it should be like:

```
[SentiSynset('decelerate.v.01'), SentiSynset('slow.v.02'), \
SentiSynset('slow.v.03'), SentiSynset('slow.a.01'),SentiSynset('slow.a.02'), \
SentiSynset('slow.a.04'), SentiSynset('slowly.r.01'),SentiSynset('behind.r.03')]
```

I am really sorry if my question is vague or silly but i am new to python and nltk and not getting this one.And how can i get the sentiment scores of these synsets using sentiwordnet.

Comment: Being new to python and jumping into Sentiment Analysis? That's bold!

Answer (score 2):

You are using python3 . In python3 **filter** function returns a **filter object** instead of list.

senti_synsets method is defined in [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/sentiwordnet.html#SentiWordNetCorpusReader.senti_synsets) like this.

```
def senti_synsets(self, string, pos=None):
        from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
        sentis = []
        synset_list = wn.synsets(string, pos)
        for synset in synset_list:
            sentis.append(self.senti_synset(synset.name()))
        sentis = filter(lambda x : x, sentis)
        return sentis
```

and since you are using python3, senti_synsets method returns a python filter object.

You can convert that filter object into list.

```
 synsets=list(swn.senti_synsets('slow'))
 synsets
```

output

```
[SentiSynset('decelerate.v.01'),
 SentiSynset('slow.v.02'),
 SentiSynset('slow.v.03'),
 SentiSynset('slow.a.01'),
 SentiSynset('slow.a.02'),
 SentiSynset('dense.s.04'),
 SentiSynset('slow.a.04'),
 SentiSynset('boring.s.01'),
 SentiSynset('dull.s.08'),
 SentiSynset('slowly.r.01'),
 SentiSynset('behind.r.03')]
```

Comment: Why? Where? How does it help? Any reference?

Answer (score 0):

```
from nltk.corpus import sentiwordnet as swn
good = swn.senti_synsets('good', 'n')

posscore=0
negscore=0
for synst in good:

    posscore=posscore+synst.pos_score()
    negscore=negscore+synst.neg_score()


print(posscore)
print(negscore)
```

better to get an average.